# Is there any prerequisite to use before/after in systemd service file?

Tags: service, systemd

I have two service files and both look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=A service
[Service]
User=root
#change this to your workspace
WorkingDirectory=/data/acloud/repository/lib
#path to executable. 
#executable is a bash script file I created to run the application jar file
ExecStart=/data/acloud/repository/lib/program.sh
SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I added `After=` in one of the file hoping it would start only after the other service is started. But its not working. It starts without any problem even if the other service is not started. I don't understand why.

Also, I put `Requires=<other service>` in the same file and removed the `after` clause. It works as expected. The other service starts automatically when this one is started.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Clarification: Both service file look like whats shown in description but obviously have different names and have different ExecStart paths.

Comment: The documentation explains the meaning of both After and Requires. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html Is anything still unclear after reading it? If so, could you add what is unclear to your question?

Comment: @Michal, I've gone through the document you shared. My understanding is if foo.service has an entry like After=bar.service, then foo.bar will start only after the bar.service is started. And only the entry After=bar.service is enough to achieve this, no other changes needed. But in my case foo.bar starts just fine even before bar.service. 

One detail I left out is both are originally spring boot apps and I start them up using 'sudo systemctl start foo/bar'.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I think that this question would probably better fit ServerFault, SuperUser or Unix SE. Actually there is already https://serverfault.com/questions/812584/in-systemd-whats-the-difference-between-after-and-requires Also https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-unit-dependencies-and-order/ seems to have quite a clear explanation.